# How to see ldapAgentPassword of ldap configuration in plaintext

Tags: owncloud, nextcloud

We have LDAP authentication configured in our owncloud and cannot remember the password for our ldap backend anymore. I have found the `ldap_agent_password` setting in the database which seems to store an encrypted string of that password.

How to display the password in plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ldap password isn't stored encrypted, instead it's only encoded with base64.
To fetch it from the database use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_appconfig WHERE appid='user_ldap' AND configkey='ldap_agent_password';
```

Copy the configvalue and paste it in the following command:

```
echo "VALUE" | base64 -d
```

For example if the query returns `dGVzdDQyCg==` execute:

```
echo "dGVzdDQyCg==" | base64 -d
```

which will return `test42`.

Comment: Thanks mate! I'm not sure if this is because of bsd vs linux but on macOS the option is `-D` instead of `-d`.